Can't run python on window
Since the most recent update to Windows 10, I have been seeing this message every time I try to do anything with Python
this app can't run on your pc to find a version for your pc check with the software publisher(https://i.sstatic.net/XoRegMcg.png)
I have reinstalled it, tried running it as administrator. Nothing works. I installed python 3.11 through anaconda3


Install Python (Link: https://www.python.org/downloads/ )
Open cmd and check its version (python –version or python -V)
Open Google Collab, then login
Create new Notebook
Start writing python code and running it
Check Image for details


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
